# MongoDB Query Find multiple fields or documents properly

Tags: mongodb

In my collection I got two fields, `gender` and `country`.

In the `gender` field they are all "female" and each of them are in different `country`.

I tried to query the collection:

```
return Meteor.users.find(
    { 
        _id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()},
        $or: [ { "country": "Australia" }, { "gender": "" } ]
    }).fetch();
```

The result goes like this:

When set the `gender` to "null" or empty it gives me all the user who are in Australia.

But when I set `gender` to "female" and `country` to "Australia" it gives me all the female users from different countries which is supposed to be only `female` from Australia. It seems it ignores first argument which is the `country`.

Is there a way to have it more accurate? Please help thank you.

My Goal is:

To make the database query more accurately and bw able to adopt to the changes.

Example:

Going back to the issue above, when I added the "gender" on the search query, it should only look for female users whose country is Australia. Not all females from different countries.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a little bit by editing it to include some sample documents and the expected output as currently it's hard to follow? If all the documents have the `gender` field as "female" but with different `country` values, then why can't you just query on the `country` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out a solution on how to sort this out. It is a bit long code but it did the trick.

1. I scanned the data I got and remove null data, in my case above if gender is == to "" then ignore it else get its data if exist. I did it via loop.
2. Using array push I was able to insert object. Ex: If country is not null then:

   **variable**.push('{"+objectPropertyName[i]+"'+':'+'"'+objectValue[i]+'"}');

The output of this looks like this:

```
["{"country":"Australia"}", "{"gender":"female"}"]
```

by parsing it to JSON then becomes an object.

Once all the objects necessary for the query is set the I can query the mongo through:

```
db.collection.find({"_id": {$ne: Meteor.userId()}, $and: **variable**}).fetch();
```

So far it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to meet both the conditions female as well as country, it should be and

```
return Meteor.users.find({ _id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}, 
                           $and: [{"country": "Australia"}, 
                                  {"gender": "female"}]
                         }).fetch();
```

Comment: A good suggestion, I tried it but when set the gender or country to null or no value it won't display any result.

I am creating a filter search feature and sometimes some fields can be null or no value that is why I decided to use "OR" so it can ignore null value and execute only the ones with values.

Comment: @WebsiteIsFun if you really "always" want "female" in gender then it **is** an "AND" condtion. The only reall tweak here is that "all" MongoDB query conditions are already "AND" conditions, so `{ "_id": { "$ne": Meteor.userId(), "country": "Australia", "gender": "female" }` or if you are really not concrete on the country value then use `$or` just there: `{ "_id": { "$ne": Meteor.userId(), "gender": "female", "$or": [{ "country": { "$in": ["Australia",null] }, { "country": { "$exists": false } }] }` as is appropriate for however the data is stored.

Comment: @WebsiteIsFun Point is your described logic in your question indicates "AND" rather than "OR". At the most an "OR" would only apply to multiple possible values of a field, being covered by both the `$in` ( a shortended `$or` for a value or `null` ) and the `$exists` test should the field not even be present.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect solution, but you can do something like this:

```
var filter = { };

filter._id = { $ne: Meteor.userId() };

if(Meteor.country()){
    filter.country = Meteor.country();
};

if(Meteor.gender()){
    filter.gender = Meteor.gender();
};

return Meteor.users.find(filter).fetch();
```

Also, since you don't know on what basis the query is to be performed, you shouldn't use operators like `$and` or `$or`

The query document that you prepared queries for all the users, where `_id` is not equal to `Meteor.userId()` **AND** `country` = AUSTRALIA **or** `gender` = FEMALE.

Also the solution that [zangw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011380/zangw) suggested, there $and isn't required as all the criteria in the query document to the `find` method is implicitly ANDed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much . . let me try to do some test with your solution . .